# I want to upload the magento Extension file in magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext is instantalerts-1.1.0

extension key **instantalerts**

Upload package file for version "1.0.1" of extension "Spring Edge India - SMS Notification "

[image: error]

Comment: Give more detail about that error and that extension that you want you install

Comment: this is the error that i am facing to upload the file in magento connect

Comment: Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext is instantalerts-1.1.0

Comment: Might Be possible you have selected key of magento connect1.0 instead of 2.0

Comment: What is your extension package file name? I think you should try renaming it to instantalerts-1.0.1 with your package file ext.

Comment: i tried that one also it will showing another error

Answer (score 0):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is asking about listing an extension, not installing one.

Comment: @RyanH yes i am trying to upload the my own extension file in magento connect.thats way i am  getting above error